# perl: How to distinguish if file does not exists or I don't have permissions to the path

Tags: perl, unix

I need to test if a file/directory exists on the filesystem using Perl in a unix environment. I tried using the file test -e, but that does not distinguish between

- The file/directory does not exist.
- You don't have permission to read in the parent folder.

I could check what is in the $? variable after the test and search for "Permission denied", but it doesn't sound like the right thing to do.

Any advice?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you don't have permissions to read, it effectively *doesn't* exist.

Comment: I know these file existed and somebody added them to the list of files "to watch". Now I cannot read them. It is important I can distinguish between "it definitely is not there any more" to "it might still be there, I don't have the permission to check".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-e` is just a call to `stat`, and like other systems calls, it sets `$!` and `%!` when it returns false.

```
if (-e $qfn) {
    print "ok\n";
}
elsif ($!{ENOENT}) {
    print "Doesn't exist\n";
}
else {
    die $!;
}
```

For example,

```
$ mkdir foo

$ touch foo/file

$ chmod 0 foo

$ perl x.pl foo/file
Permission denied at x.pl line 10.

$ perl x.pl bar/file
Doesn't exist

$ perl x.pl x.pl
ok
```

Comment: `EACCES` for Permission denied

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about %!. I'll look into it.